# Python readline() and Counter causes MemoryError on very long line

Tags: python, memory, readline

I'm having the issue of a memory error.

```
pifile = 'pibillion.txt'
with open(pifile, "r+") as a:
    data = str(a.readline())
    c = Counter(data)
```

All my code does is read one very very large line of the digits of pi. The txt file is only 953 MB. I have 8 GB RAM. I'm guessing the error is that it runs into the String size limitation but I'm not sure. The rest of the code inserts a line break at increments of two. Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how to continue with this.

The exact error I'm getting is this:

```
data = str(a.readline())
   MemoryError
```

Comment: Can you share the specific error you get?

Comment: a number with 1 billion digits is a quite a challenge for the default implementation in most languages... better ask about the problem you are trying to solve, not about the problem with your solution.

Comment: Do this iteratively, python is not lazy.

Comment: @PauloScardine Why can't you read OPs question? It clearly states what he is trying to do.

Comment: @simonzack looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me. It is unlikely he really needs a 1 billion character string (you sounded very rude, by the way).

Comment: @PauloScardine He wants to "(insert) a line break at increments of two".

Comment: @simonzack I can't tell if you don't have a clue about what is the "XY problem" or if you think the question doesn't suffer from it.

Comment: `readline` already returns a string; no need to pass the value to `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is not inherently lazy (like haskell), so reading a string will put it all in memory. Add to that some string conversions and you're out of memory. Instead, do this iteratively, like the following.

Note that I have used a new file, as files are usually stored contiguously, so inserting is very expensive.

```
with open('pibillion.txt', 'r') as old_file, open('pibillion_.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    while True:
        c = old_file.read(2)
        if not c:
            break
        new_file.write(c + '\n')
```

Comment: BTW, I upvoted your answer - but would not say "Python is not lazy" because there is a lot of lazy evaluation in Python, for example with generators and generator expressions.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thanks, fixed. I hope we can put the not so friendly comments above behind us.

Comment: Accept my apologies as well. :-)

Comment: @simonzack Thank you so much, for some reason I hadn't thought of this solution. I guess I was on full tilt and was being stubborn with changing my code. Works brilliantly and now I can continue on with this project. Thanks again, so much.